# Why do I need 'Classic Mode' in ASP.NET MVC in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp-classic, integrated-pipeline-mode

Why do I need 'Classic Mode' in ASP.NET MVC in IIS7?

Integrated Mode provides more features and better performance, so why do I need Classic Mode?

Perhaps I dont understand the differences, please can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline mode is a property of the Application Pool not ASP.NET MVC.

It may be that you have an ASP.NET MVC application but also some legacy Classic ASP code that requires Classic Mode to be able to function properly.

But if your application is pure ASP.NET MVC then yes your should run in Integrated Pipeline mode.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Kev already mentioned in his answer, it's also about the configuration entries.

You use different web.config elements to configure handlers when you run it in Classic Mode than in Integrated Mode. That may be the case of the application you are trying, but it's certainly no a reason to do it. You can have configurations for both in the web.config, so it would work the same regardless of Classic vs. Integrated.

Comment: Re: *You use different web.config elements to configure handlers when you run it in Classic Mode than in Integrated Mode* .  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx